# How to properly write a Rails API controller to perform a full sync to an iOS client

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api-design, data-synchronization, offlineapps

I'm currently developing an API that will be providing data to a web app and an iOS app. The iOS application will support offline use so it will require a "sync" to grab everything that the API currently has.

I've looked around for examples on a 'accepted' way to perform the sync that will pass all the entities in 1 request but haven't been able to find anything concrete. Perhaps I'm not using the correct words as I feel this would be very common now with the rise in popularity single page web applications and the separation of frontend and backend.

A React Frontend with a Rails backend api would also require a larger "sync" on initial load right?

My current idea is to have a Sync controller that contains a initial sync action that would collect all the entities and return them as a large payload.

```
class SyncController < ApplicationController
    def initial_iOS_sync
      ...
      return all the entities that the iOS application would require
      ...
    end
end
```

I'm trying to use best practices in the API but feel like using 'initial_ios_sync' is not the correct naming convention for CRUD actions in an API. From what I've read, usually you should only use index, create, update, and delete as the actions for resources in an API.

What would be a correct way to approach this issue?

Does an larger initial sync break any best practices?

What do other application that require this kind of action do to achieve similar results?

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the entire user/application state to the client on  the first load? Or is the goal something else?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner The idea is to pass all the entities required to provide full functionality offline. The device could sync, go into an area with little to no reception but still be able to perform all actions. When the device comes back into an area with reception, it would upload all its data to the API. I've used UUID to prevent any conflicts on ids. So I'm trying to pass as much as required on first load.

Comment: If the device were to be in a service area, regular API calls could be made along side actions performed on the iOS device.

Comment: > I'm trying to use best practices in the API but feel like using 'initial_ios_sync' is not the correct naming convention for CRUD actions in an API.

The idea behind naming conventions is for sanity, some metaprogramming, and it allows other developers to jump right in and not have to dig around much (if at all) for where something is supposed to go. Having said, it's okay to cheat now and then, and there's no harm doing it.

Comment: The RESTful api would probably look like: GET /sync/ to get all the data, and PUT/PATCH /sync/ to send large updates.

Comment: However, You'll probably want to carefully consider your design so as to reduce duplication of code between controllers. This is not a simple task, and makes it easy to tangle up a lot of logic that would otherwise be separated. That can be avoided, but it requires careful attention.

Comment: I used 'sync' as the name because it was an easy choice. But if you can come up with a better word that describes what that data is, what you would call it, what the data describes (maybe "app state" or something like that), go with that instead.